How to implement a pause menu in my javascript canvas animation?
I'm adding menu states to an interactive canvas animation based on my edits to this MDN exercise. I want to pause the animation when I press esc (not hide it under an opaque overlay) and resume when I click "return". At this point I feel like I don't know enough JS to implement it, or whether it's possible in JS.
(As you can see, I'm a beginner and this is for me to practice simple JS and CSS, not make a proper browser game, so "real world" solutions are not the focus)
The pause menu opens and closes as intended, but I don't know how to implement the actual pause!
I tried do { } while (clicked === false); and the page froze. I looked it up and learned that waiting and blocking is different, and that you should never do this. I found out about async/await and understood some simple examples. But I didn't figure out how to apply that to functions in my code. I haven't gotten to the asynchronous JS part of my coding course yet and it really confuses me. Do I need to learn about asyncronous JS first to solve this? Some replies to similar questions sound like in JS you're not supposed to pause code execution that way at all... I have no idea how to approach this anymore.
In the MRE snippet I've removed unrelated elements and styling, and replaced the canvas with a random number generator.


// pause-test.js

let testArea = document.getElementById("test-area");
let pauseScreen = document.getElementById("pause-menu");
let resumeButton = document.getElementById("resume-button");

function random(min, max) {
  return Math.round(min + ((max - min) * Math.random()));
}

function idleMode() {
  // removed canvas and shapes declarations
  // draw(shapes);

  draw();

  // esc should open pause menu
  document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    if ((event.key === "Escape")) {
      console.log("esc in animation()");
      pauseMenu();
    }
  })
}

idleMode();

function draw() {
  function loop() {
    // removed frame drawing functions
    // instead display a random number every second 
    let num = random(0, 10000000);
    testArea.textContent = `${num}`;
    setTimeout(() => {
      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }, 1000);
    return;
  }
  loop();
}

function pauseMenu() {
  // absolute positioned on top of the canvas
  pauseScreen.classList.remove("hide");
  console.log("paused");

  // QUESTION: How to pause animation until this event fires?
  resumeButton.addEventListener("click", pauseResume);

  return;
}

function pauseResume() {
  console.log("unpaused");
  pauseScreen.classList.add("hide");
  return;
}
<main>
  <div class="display">
    <p id="test-area">test area</p>
    <!-- <canvas tabindex='1'></canvas> -->

    <section id="pause-menu" class="hide">
      <header>Paused</header>
      <button id="resume-button">resume</button>
      <!-- <button id="exit-button">exit</button> -->
    </section>
  </div>
</main>




Make a global variable : var isPaused = false;
Then in your pause/resume method set it to either true/false:
And in your setTimeout method just modify : if( !paused ) { requestAnimationFrame .... }
Added this as comment, since its a simple solution.

@MrMT Thank you! Your solution made it pause, which is a huge improvement. It doesn't resume though... I think after passing over if (!isPaused) once the current line exits loop() altogether; I'm still figuring out what to do about that

Solution (thanks to @MrMT's answer in comments):
var isPaused = false;
// replaced a random number with a counter to check that it doesn't reset
let num = 0;

function draw() {
    function loop() {

        if (isPaused === false) {
            num++;
            testArea.textContent = `${num}`;
        }
        else {
            return;
        }

        setTimeout(() => { requestAnimationFrame(loop); }, 200);
        return;
    }
    loop();
}

function pauseMenu() {
    pauseScreen.classList.remove("hide");
    console.log("paused");
    isPaused = true;

    resumeButton.addEventListener("click", pauseResume);
}

function pauseResume() {
    isPaused = false;
    console.log("unpaused");
    pauseScreen.classList.add("hide");
    
    // otherwise after passing over if (isPaused === false)
    // current line will exit the loop altogether!
    draw();
}

It worked in my canvas animation code too with a few edits. Much appreciated!
